# Is there a way to show an explanation of an option in a dropdown menu in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a dropdown menu in Excel (cell A2) for a performance review sheet, which has the usual rating options (Excellent, Great, Good, etc.). Currently I have it tied to an IF statement in cell B2 to populate with an explanation of the chosen rating.

Is there a way to bring up the explanation in a pop-up when hovering over that rating in the dropdown?

For example, if I hovered over Excellent a pop up would show what that rating means.

Comment: Data validation allows you to make a drop down list and enter a info text, even an error message text.

Comment: @Damian this could work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. First, insert a comment by right-clicking on A2 and Insert Comment (this can be done using VBA, but for the simplicity of the example do it manually).

Then use the `Worksheet_Change` event within the sheet to trigger when the dropdown is changed. Send the text value to another function that edits the comment with the desired description (this can be done in the `Worksheet_Change` function but I perfer to split. See below code:

In the sheet module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Intersect(Target, Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Call ChangeText(Range("A2").Text)

End Sub
```

In a normal module:

```
Sub ChangeText(iTxt As String)

    If iTxt = "Excellent" Then
        Range("A2").Comment.Text Text:="A"
    ElseIf iTxt = "Good" Then
        Range("A2").Comment.Text Text:="B"
    ElseIf iTxt = "Bad" Then
        Range("A2").Comment.Text Text:="C"
    End If

End Sub
```